# How to reference the class itself in python

Tags: python

I want to have simple class constants in python like this:

```
class FooBarBaz:
    BAR = 123

    @staticmethod
    def getBar():
        return BAR # this would not work, of course

        return FooBarBaz.BAR # this would work but is "way too long"
```

Is there a shorter way to reference the class itself from inside a method, not the current instance? It's not only for static methods but in general, like a `__class__` keyword or something.

Comment: I guess you're looking for classmethods, not statics.

Comment: @thg435 nvm good point. submit that as an answer...

Comment: Forget about if it's static or not. I'm looking for general alias for the class itself from the class scope, not it's instance (if any). It could be a variable belonging to the class, method belonging to the class. I want something like `self` is referencing the instance of the class, but referencing the class.

Comment: You mean `type(self)`?

Comment: in classmethods the first argument passed to function is class (commonly denoted cls) http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod

Comment: Yes, it seems that I need @classmethod after all. Add as an answer to accept :)

Comment: there is no `self` when you use `@staticmethod`. @Veseliq You can't just *forget* if it's static or not, it makes a huge difference because static methods are not dependent on the class at all and so you aren't supposed to access it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need `@classmethod` rather than `@staticmethod` - a class method will get passed a reference to the class (where a method will get `self`), so you can look up attributes on it.

```
class FooBarBaz:
    BAR = 123

    @classmethod
    def getBar(cls):
        return cls.BAR
```

Answer (score 15):

Actually, there is `__class__` in python 3:

```
Python 3.2.3 (v3.2.3:3d0686d90f55, Apr 10 2012, 11:25:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A:
...     @staticmethod
...     def foo():
...         print(__class__)
... 
>>> A.foo()
<class '__main__.A'>
>>>
```

See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135 for the rationale why it has been added.

No idea about how to achieve the same in py2, I guess [this is not possible](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+static+method+get+class).

Comment: Good point. I'm using 2.7 so I accepted the other answer I actually used in my code.

Comment: @Veseliq: Huh? You said you're not looking for class methods?

Comment: Check the comments, I actually didn't know what @classmethod is :)

Comment: @Veseliq: ah, ok then. Do note however, that `cls` is quite different from `__class__` - it doesn't tell you where the method is defined, only how it's called.

Comment: And I believe inside an instance method (with `self` available) you can use `self.__class__`.